# Linked List Remove Duplicates

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, data-structures, linked-list

Please help! I feel like I am so close!

I am trying to solve a remove duplicates problem utilizing a helper function that will return the next value to chain onto the current node.

```
"use strict";

const SLinkedList = require("./linked-list.js");

function removeDups(list) {

  const visitedNumbers = {}
  let current = list.head

  let walk = (node) => {
    if (!visitedNumbers[node.value]) {
      console.log('Adding new number', node.value)
      return node
    }
    console.log('Number already exists: ', node.value)
    walk(node.next)
  }

  while (current) {
    console.log('This is current.value in while loop', current.value)
    visitedNumbers[current.value] = true
    current.next = walk(current.next)
    current = current.next
  }
  return list
}

const newList = new SLinkedList();
newList.append(1).append(2).append(1).append(3).append(3);
console.log('ORIGINAL: ', removeDups(newList).toString())
```

This is the expected correct output.

`ORIGINAL: { 1 } -> { 2 } -> { 3 } -> NULL`

I pinpointed the problem to possibly be from the call stack of the recursion "walk" function.. Anyone know what my problem may be?

Comment: Sorry, the correct answer should be: 
ORIGINAL: { 1 } -> { 2 } -> { 3 } -> NULL

Comment: You can edit your post to include that correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing `return walk(node.next)` so after finding a duplicate it will never return anything.  On the 3rd recursion, finding {3} it will `return node`, but that node will never actually be returned to `current.next`.

Comment: SADIKULHWASLIDHWAKHDLWUAHKLDHAKLWHDKLWAHKLDHAWL I literally found the answer right before I cam eback here to post it. Thank you so much @Matriarx

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution with the help of Matriarx

```
"use strict";

const SLinkedList = require("./linked-list.js");

function removeDups(list) {

  const visitedNumbers = {}
  let current = list.head

  let walk = (node) => {
    if (node) {
      if (!visitedNumbers[node.value] || null) {
        return node
      }
      return walk(node.next)
    }
  }

  while (current) {
    visitedNumbers[current.value] = true
    current.next = walk(current.next)
    current = current.next
  }
  return list
}
```

I also had to add a if statement so that it would only work if the 'node' parameter was truthy

Comment: ALso note that the `walk` function doesn't need to be recursive. It could just be a while loop. I think the `|| null` is dead code (it means the same as or false which will become false), however if the next nodes all are duplicates you'll end up returning `undefined` as `current.next` while in your text seem to want `null`

Comment: By the way, just some syntactic sugar but you can do ````if (node && !visitedNumbers[node.value])````.  The ````|| null```` will also never execute, you might have wanted to do ````node.value === null````.

Answer (score 0):

**This should work:**

```js
function removeDumps(list) {
    const memo = new Set()

    function walk(node) {
        if(node) {
            return !memo.has(node.value) ? node : walk(node.next)
        }
        return null
    }
    
    let node = list.head
    
    while(node) {
        if(!memo.has(node.value)) {
            memo.add(node.value)
        }
        
        node.next = walk(node.next)
        node = node.next
    }

    return list
}
```

**And a version without recursion**

```js
function removeDumps(list) {
    const memo = new Set()
    
    let node = list.head
    let last = null
    while(node) {
        if(memo.has(node.value)) {
            node = node.next
            continue
        }
        memo.add(node.value)
        if(last) {
            last.next = node
        }
        last = node
        node = node.next
    }

    return list
}
```

*Please comment if it don't ;)*